# Converting integers for loop in Python - Loop ignores function value?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on a number guessing game and can't seem to get my loop to work while utilizing a function. I was manually typing out conversion under each if/elif in the block, but that was tedious and only checking for integers - string inputs couldn't read and broke the system.

I tried creating a conversion function to check the values and determine if it was an integer or string and change the variable type accordingly. However this results in an infinite loop fo line 18.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Heads up, I do have the random.py script from Python.org and am importing it so the game plays differently each time.

```
from random import randint
print 'Hello, my name is Skynet. What\'s yours?'
myName = raw_input()
print 'Good to meet you, ' + myName + '! Let\'s play a game.'
print 'I\'m thinking of a number between between 1 and 20, can you guess it?'
pcNum = randint(1,20)
myNum = raw_input()
def checkNum(myNum):
        try:
            int(myNum)
        except ValueError:
            returnVAL = 'That\'s not a number I know, try again.'
        else:
            returnVAL = int(myNum)
        return returnVAL    
while myNum != pcNum:
    if myNum > pcNum:
        print 'That\'s too high! Try again.'
        myNum = raw_input()
        checkNum(myNum)
    else:
        print 'That\'s too low! Try again.'
        myNum = raw_input()
        checkNum(myNum)
if myNum == pcNum:
    print 'Good job, my number was ' + str(pcNum) + ' too! Good job, ' + myName
```

Any input is appreciated. I did some browsing here and got some a better idea of how to pull this off, or so I thought, and now here I am asking. First post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "I'm thinking of a number between between 1 and 20, can you guess it?"
while True:
    guess = raw_input("What's your guess? ")
    try:
        guess = int(guess, 10)
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a number I know, try again."
        continue
    if guess == pcNum:
        ...
        break
    elif guess > pcNum:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Fred! I take it that while True sets a loop that will run as long as it's continued and end upon break?

I'm just getting into Python, I have some experience with JavaScript and GML (Game Maker), so it's a bit weird to me at the moment.

Soon it should feel natural and these conventions will make sense.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, True is Python value, as are False, None, 42, and [3, 5].

Comment: It's like when I first saw 'if variableName {'. Oh, the variable has a value and therefore is true so it works, but it totally wasn't obvious to me at the time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix responsibilities. It is wrong to have `myNum` be both a number and an error message.

Also, think what you want to do when a user enters a non-number. In your case, the user's guess is `"That's not a number I know, try again."`, and it's being compared to `pcNum`; this makes no sense. If it was me, I would want the user to enter the number again. So rather than `checkNum`, I want `input_valid_integer`:

```
def input_valid_integer():
    result = None
    while result is None:
        text = raw_input()
        try:
            result = int(text)
        except ValueError:
            print 'That\'s not a number I know, try again.'
    return result
```

Comment: Oops! That was meant to be the reply to a non-integer, not its value. Thanks for straightening that out for me. This is the third time I've rewritten the script in the last half an hour, I'm getting sloppy and tired. Things are working now, though. Guess I should read through the code again rather than focus on a presumed problem.

Stack Overflow users rock.